# ARM Template - Deployment slot keyvault permissions

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault

Trying to assign permissions for the app service deployment slot to keyvault and having a hell of a time getting it

```
{
                        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
                        "objectId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/slots', parameters('azureAppService').webSiteName, 'DEV').identity.principalId]",
                        "permissions": {
                            "secrets": [
                                "Get"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, the template validation goes through, but upon deployment but I get an error. How do I specify the resource ID for the deployment slot?

Here is the error

```
{
"status": "Failed",
"error": {
    "code": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "Unable to process template language expressions for resource '/subscriptions/---/resourceGroups/Test/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/KEYVAULT-TEST' at line '447' and column '9'. 'The language expression property 'identity' can't be evaluated.'",
    "additionalInfo": [
        {
            "type": "TemplateViolation",
            "info": {
                "lineNumber": 447,
                "linePosition": 9,
                "path": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: could you share the full error message with us ?

Comment: did you enable managed identity on the slot ?

Comment: Yes I did enabled the managed identity on the slot

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the `reference` function (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#reference)):

```
[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/slots', parameters('azureAppService').webSiteName, 'DEV'), '2022-03-01', 'full').identity.principalId]
```

Comment: THis is the error that I get when I changed that 
        "message": "Unable to process template language expressions for resource '/subscriptions/--/resourceGroups/Test/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/KEYVAULT-TEST' at line '444' and column '9'. 'The language expression property 'identity' doesn't exist, available properties are 'apiVersion, location, kind, properties, condition, deploymentResourceLineInfo, existing, isConditionTrue, subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, scope, resourceId, referenceApiVersion, isTemplateResource, isAction, provisioningOperation'.'",

Answer (score -1):

```
"[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/slots', parameters('azureAppService').webSiteName, 'DEV'), '2020-06-01', 'full').identity.principalId]",
```

So it seems that even tho I added this to the deployment slots

```
"identity": {
                            "type": "SystemAssigned"
        },
```

It wasn't creating the systemassigned identity. Once I manually created it and then redeployed the ARM template, it worked.